# wordpress ajax and foreach - doesn't return an array

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

last time I fight with Ajax and WordPress. 
I have a problem using Ajax wants to load the Posts of the same category ... 
in response is replaced Object, only one entry.

Where to find the problem?

**ajax.js**

```
var $fnWritePostGrid = function (idCat) {
        var data = {
            type: 'POST',
            url: ajaxOptions.url,
            action: 'kk_load_servicesGrid',
            idCat: idCat
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: ajaxOptions.url,
            data: data,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            }

        });
        return false;

    };
```

**functions.php**

```
$cat_id = $_POST['idCat'];
$args = array(
    'category' => $cat_id,
    'posts_per_page' => 8,
    'order' => 'DESC'
);  

$posts = get_posts($args);

foreach($posts as $post) {
    $postID = sanitize_text_field($post->ID);
    $postTitle = sanitize_text_field($post->post_title);
    $postContent = sanitize_text_field($post->post_content);

    $response = array(
        'ID' => $postID,
        'title' => $postTitle,
        'content' => $postContent
    );
    echo json_encode($response);
    exit;
}
```

In summary, the code works but doesn't return an array of entries, only the first entry in the category.

Please help and thanks in advance.

Comment: Try outputting your JSON *after* the foreach loop, rather than inside it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though your PHP is exiting the thread after the first iteration of your foreach loop:

```
echo json_encode($response);
exit;
```

What you likely want to do instead is create an array of all of the posts that you want to return -- something like this:

```
$responses = array();

foreach($posts as $post) {
    $postID = sanitize_text_field($post->ID);
    $postTitle = sanitize_text_field($post->post_title);
    $postContent = sanitize_text_field($post->post_content);

    $response = array(
        'ID' => $postID,
        'title' => $postTitle,
        'content' => $postContent
    );
    array_push($responses, $response)
}

echo json_encode($responses);
exit;
```

This way you'll actually be returning a JSON array of objects, rather than a single JSON object.